# Catia VBA-How to subtract selected item

Tags: vba, catia

I wan to write a code to select parent item in catia.
I select a object then run this code.

```
Set Sel = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
Sel.Add Sel.Item(1).LeafProduct.Parent.Parent
```

then 2 item selected: item(1),item(2).
How to subtract item(1)? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _subtract item_? Do you want to subtract bodies from different parts with Boolean operation?

Comment: like i selected 2 part in assembly. Now i need unselect item(1) .
How can i do this with VBA?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. With `Sel.Remove2(i)` you can remove the _i-th_ item. Or do you want to invert the selection?

Comment: yeah, it worked. that's exactly what i want.
It's so simple but I can't find it anywhere.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You find these methods/objects in the documentation: _V5Automation.chm_ in the catia install directory